# Schema design for selecting multiple U.S. states, or "all"

Tags: mysql, schema

As a simplified example, imagine that I'm selling widgets.  I sell them nationwide (in both the U.S. and Canada) but there are some that can only be sold in certain areas (one or more U.S. states or Canadian provinces).

I'd like a good way to store this information, coupled with a fast way to query for the widgets that are available to a given user.  "U.S., 50 states and D.C." is the most common value, so I'd rather not insert 51 rows.

MySQL doesn't support bitmap indexes, so that's ruled out.

Here are some combinations:

- U.S. 50 states and D.C.
- U.S. 50 states, D.C., Canada, but not Quebec.
- U.S. 48 contiguous states and D.C.
- U.S., D.C., but not Colorado
- U.S., D.C., and territories (Puerto Rico, etc).

My user will have given me one value for their state/province and country.

Can you suggest a schema that provides good storage and fast matching?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a MySQL [SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) type, assuming that you can keep your dataset down to 64 items (or, use multiple sets based on other conditions).

---

I thought I would expand on my answer, because I think some people just don't understand the power of the set.  Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Test` (
  `setid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `setname` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `setstate` set('AK','AL','AR','AZ','CA','CO','CT','DC','DE','FL','GA','HI','IA','ID','IL','IN','KS','KY','LA','MA','MD','ME','MI','MN','MO','MS','MT','NC','ND','NE','NH','NJ','NM','NV','NY','OH','OK','OR','PA','RI','SC','SD','TN','TX','UT','VA','VT','WA','WI','WV','WY') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`setid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into `Test` values('1','test','AZ,CA,NJ,NM,NY,VA,VT');
```

Note that we use a single set field for states.  More complex uses will likely require use of multiple sets, but the slightly more horizontal qword for each record may be cheaper than adding a large # of extra join operations on a lookup table that could easily reach a huge # of records on its on.

Below are 3 (functionally) equivalent pulls.  Note that the bitmask is very much the fastest way to pull this data:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE setstate & 1000;
```

For test #1, We use 1000 as the bitmask, because this corresponds to item #4 in our list (AZ).  This is, by far, the fastest method... and there are few ways to store this data which will give you faster result potential.

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE setstate LIKE '%AZ%';
```

This method can use indexes, but will be somewhat slow because of the fuzzy match.

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE FIND_IN_SET('AZ',setstate);
```

This method will be faster than the fuzzy match, but its nature will pretty much require the use of a temporary table in most real-world uses.

Comment: This seems to satisfy the storage aspect, but I can't join from 'users.state' to 'widgets.states' and it appears that I'd have to do a `FIND_IN_SET`, which won't use any indexes.  True?  Workaround?

Comment: and also it will limit your business to 64 countries/province combinations

Comment: @AlainCollins - In pure SQL, the join will be difficult because the set names are in the schema, not in the data.  If you're using some flavor of Dynamic SQL, you can use a bitmask (extremely fast)... so it does depend on your environment.

Comment: @Sir Rufo - Actually, it will limit you to 2^64 (~18 pentillion) combinations.  You may only have 64 possibilities per set, but again... it is pretty easy to chain sets together.

Comment: the combinations i mentioned were country and state/province. e.g. US-NY,US-KY,US-CA,...

Comment: @SirRufo - I've looked at this comment a few times.  And I still have no idea what you're saying.  US-NY isn't really a combination, and even if it was (guessing here, since I've no idea why you'd make a distinction), you'd just use discrete fields for country and state since they're really separate pieces of information.  Sure, you could use something 'easier', but it really depends on exactly what the op needs.

Comment: OP wants to store if an item can be selled to a customer living in `USA-New York` (US-NY) or in Germany-Bayern (DE-BY) or in Canada-Quebec City (CA-QC). Maybe i didn't get the point, how you want to store that information (country/state) separated within your set (or maybe sets). A small sample would be helpful

Comment: @SirRufo - First off, I think you're making assumptions about what the OP wants that isn't in the text (or even subtext). However, I'll bite - In my updated example, setstate is simply for US states. We could easily add another which could store Canada, allowing the user to mix & match countries with ease. The records may become wider, but would have a fraction of the records in the system you specify below. I'll guarantee that speed in mine will kill yours in most real-world situations. Plus, there are other concerns like maintenance that I'd argue is easier to deal with in a list like this.

Comment: One set for each country (e.g. Puerto Rico is mentioned and Canada) ... i wouldn't choose that ever (normalization, speed, maintance, extending) but it's just a single mind from me

Comment: My project is really North America-centric, so I'm not opposed to having to columns as was suggested.  I may need to revisit it when I take over the entire world.

Comment: @JohnGreen, thanks for the update.  I was building an example like this, but was unhappy that I was seemingly unable to use an index when joining.  An unanchored LIKE will also suffer from the same problem.  I'll have to create a large enough set of test data to see how the bitmask query performs.

Comment: I think I prefer the tradeoffs with this solution, especially in the early days of this project.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should build predefined sets of values and storing this set to the items.
With a value you retrieve the matching sets and the matching items.

```
CREATE TABLE `valuesets` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `valueset_items` (
  `valueset_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`valueset_id`,`value`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_valueset_items_valueset` FOREIGN KEY (`valueset_id`) REFERENCES `valuesets` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `valueset_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_items_valueset` (`valueset_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_items_valueset` FOREIGN KEY (`valueset_id`) REFERENCES `valuesets` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

To select all items that matching a special value

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE 
  valueset_id IN ( SELECT valueset_id 
                   FROM valueset_items 
                   WHERE `value` = 'A' )
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47617/4/0)

Comment: This is more traditional and the join would be more straight forward.  I'm worried about the UI, where a person would be tagging an item into a set.  In the US alone, there would be thousands of sets (which doesn't work for a pulldown).  I'd probably need to take the unstructured input and find or create a matching set.  Ah, tradeoffs.